# I have a command that will run in cmd but wont run as batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory

I have the below command. It runs if I run it from cmd even if I cd to any location first. How come it doesn't run if I save it as a batch file? The code checks a list of users and sees if they are disabled in AD. If any of them are it exports the list to deactivatedusers.txt. I am running the machine as admin.

```
for /f %a in (c:\test\users.txt) do net user %a /domain |findstr /C:"Account active               No" && echo %a is deactivated >>c:\test\deactivatedusers.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f %%a in (c:\test\users.txt) do net user %%a /domain |findstr /C:"Account active
```

You need to double the `%` when you execute the command from batch.